# Oracle Warehouse Builder - Splitter: Split condition

Tags: split, mapping, transformation, oracle-warehouse-builder

The oracle documentation saying

> Select the output group of the Splitter operator.
>
> The Property Inspector displays the properties of the output group.
>
> Click the Ellipsis button to the right of the Split Condition field.
>
> The Expression Builder dialog box is displayed.
>
> Define the split condition.
>
> For example, the split condition can be UPPER(INGRP1.OR_CHANNEL) = 'DIRECT'.
>
> Define expressions for the split condition of each output group except the REMAINING ROWS group.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10935/data_flow_opers.htm#WBETL26017

I do not see this Ellipsis neither the split condition field. [image: Splitter output group]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must click on the output group name and use the "Property Inspector" pane:

[image: Screenshot from OWB Designer]

If the "Property Inspector" pane is not visible you can enable it through "View" -> "Property Inspector".

Comment: Ah,  I did not notice that one :-) Thank you!